# How to reverse a graph in haskell?

Tags: haskell, graph

for an exercise I need to reverse a graph (reverse all edges), but I don't get anywhere.
So I need some help.

I am aware you might not want to solve the exercise for me, so that's not what I am asking for. I just need to get some advice...

So to get to it:

```
data Graph a = G
  { nodes :: [a]
  , successors :: a -> [a] }

reverseGraph :: Eq a => Graph a -> Graph a
```

A graph has to parameters: a list of nodes and a function that defines the successors. This function has the type: 
`a -> [a]`

for example:

```
graph1 :: Graph Int
graph1 = G [1..6] $ \case   1 -> [2,3]
                            2 -> []
                            3 -> [1,4,6]
                            4 -> [1]
                            5 -> [3,5]
                            6 -> [2,4,5]
```

the reversed graph would be:

```
reverseGraph graph1 ~>
    2 -> [1,6]
    3 -> [1,5]
    1 -> [3,4]
    4 -> [3,6]
    6 -> [3]
    5 -> [5,6]
```

I get that I need to check for each node in the input graph the successors and add for each the input node to the new successor list of the output node.

But i just don't get how to do this in Haskell.

Any help is appreciated!

---

Here is my solution for anyone who may attempt something similar:

```
reverseGraph :: Eq a => Graph a -> Graph a
reverseGraph (G nodes sucs) =  (G nodes sucs') where 
    sucs' a = getVert a nodes sucs

--Makes a list of all occurrences of v in the succeccor list.
getVert :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> (a-> [a]) -> [a]
getVert v [] succs = []
getVert v (n:ns) succs = if v `elem` succs n then [n]++getVert v ns succs else getVert v ns succs
```

Comment: If it would be oo-programming i would do it something like that:


foreach x in nodes do
 foreach s in sucs x do
  if exists s in sucs'
   add x to sucs' s
  else
   add s -> [x] to sucs'

but i dont get how to do it in functional programming

Comment: You'll need to actually call the function on each node to find out what the edges really are. This isn't a good representation for a graph whose edges you want to reverse.

Comment: Well, thats what i have. I would also prefer something different.

Comment: Sorry, you can't dig into a function like that. You first have to reify it as an explicit mapping.

Comment: `[n] ++ ...` is much better written as `n : ...`.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a reasonable declaration of the `Graph` type, which you should have done yourself. If I got it wrong, please feel free to edit.

Comment: I think it's important to mention that the type of `reverseGraph`, namely the fact that it has only an `Eq a` constraint, forces you to use a very inefficient implementation. If you had a constraint of `Ord a` or `(Eq a, Hashable a)`, then you could do considerably better.

Comment: nitpick: as you probably know you're asking specifically about a _directed_ graph. Personally if I saw a type named `Graph` I would assume it was undirected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a hint. Let's consider the reverse of `G vertices edges`.
That will be of the form `G vertices' edges'`.

It's obvious that `vertices' = vertices`.

What about `edges'`? Well, for any value `v`, `edges' v` must return

- "the list of all the `w` in `vertices` such that `edge w` contains `v` as an element"

You can translate the above English description into Haskell code using a list comprehension. You can use `` x `elem` list `` to check whether `x` is an element of `list`.

Comment: That helped me very much! Thank you!